# Can't scroll on tag wikis

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When posting a question and selecting tags, the option is available to click on a blue ⓘ to bring up the tag wiki. If it's longer than the screen, I can't scroll down to read the rest.

I'm on an iPhone 5s, using the beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.3.

I carelessly wiped out all of the scroll view's gesture recognizers forgetting that I use the view in some scrolling contexts.

Comment: Confirmed working for me on today's beta release.